# How i can get context for testing a VideoViewModel (Xamarin,NUnitLite)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, nunit

I want to test a concrete implementation of abstract VideoViewModel on android. I use VS 2013 with NUnitLite.

For create the VideoViewModel instance i need Activity Context

Here is the constructor vor VideoViewModel:

```
    public VideoViewModelAndroid(Context context, IFileSystem fileSystem)
        : base(fileSystem)
    {
        bool contextIsActivity = context is Activity;
        ExceptionUtil.ThrowIf.IsFalse(() => contextIsActivity);

        this.context = context;
        this.videoView = (context as Activity).FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView1); // Returns null for the videoView
        this.videoView.Touch += videoView_Touch;
```

}

Here is what i do to create this videoView

```
        context = MainActivity.con;
        var view = new VideoViewModelAndroid(context, fileSystem);
```

The context comes from here:

```
[Activity(Label = "IDS.Droid.Tests", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : TestSuiteActivity
{
    public static Context con;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // tests can be inside the main assembly
        AddTest(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        // or in any reference assemblies
        // AddTest (typeof (Your.Library.TestClass).Assembly);

        // Once you called base.OnCreate(), you cannot add more assemblies.
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainLayout);
        con = this;
    }

}
```

I linked the layout from the application and the id is represented in Resource.Designer.cs.

But it retuns no view after it call

```
this.videoView = (context as Activity).FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView1);
```

Any idea to resolve this problem???

Comment: Where are you inflating the layout with the VideoView? Typically you would use SetContentView() but you have that commented out.

Comment: Yes inside of a test i tried to inflate the layout (before call  new VideoViewModelAndroid(context, fileSystem) ), but this was not helpful...:-(

Comment: ViewModel with strong binding to the View? Now that is pretty uncommon...

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the context or maybe you could mock it? If you can mock it then use this package(available through nuget):

github:
https://github.com/Moq/moq4

nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/

but as others stated in comment, using context in viewModel isn't good practice. The reason for this is that ViewModel has to be platform independent. If you wanted to reuse viewModel for iOS and WinPhone you would have problem with context not existing on these platforms.

Comment: Moq ist not compatible for Xamarin.Android...:-( We have a abstract ViewModel for each platform but the are abstract and i can't test the abstract classes. I want tot test concrete implementation for the View. It works fine with wpf but not with Android...:-(

Comment: Ok, I see... still you break the MVVM pattern just by creating ViewModel for each platform. Your ViewModels should be platform independent and shouldn't contain any logic. They are used for loading data using logic written in other parts of project and presenting it to Pages/Activities/ViewController by properties. In your case, you should think about reworking your ViewModels.

Comment: The ViewModel does not have many methods. they are Play, Stop, Show... but they have litle custom logic inside like visiblestate and load videos from file system... they are platform scpecific functions that can't be platform independent...